# Can I create model named Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, naming-conventions

Can I create model named Model like below?

Will it cause some problems later?

```
# app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a model called Model...

...and yes, it could easily cause some problems later. [ActiveModel contains the class "Model"](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) already, so if you wish to ever utilize ActiveModel you set yourself up for a world of pain (or at least conflicts).